# ignore CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error on mitm attack

Tags: google-chrome, https, ssl-certificate, man-in-the-middle

i am making a mitm attack using proxy. The mitm works fine but the problem is chrome detects it. therefore, i have changed the code so it installs the certificate every time you enter a new website. However, the chrome steel says that the certificate authority is invalid. The error code chrome prints:

[image]

I used the following line to install the certificate:

```
powershell -c Import-Certificate -FilePath '{path}' -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\Root
```

I tryed to install the certificate to chrome manually as well but nothing changed.

I am searching for a way to either install the certificate proparlly or change the browser's sttings so it will ignore the error and let me in to the site. i have searched this on google but i couldn't find a wat to do so.

Comment: That is a built-in feature to Chrome, you can't bypass it by installing certificates. I am not sure if there is an option in Chrome to disable it. If not use a different Chromium based web browser.

Comment: @Robert i will to do somthing simialar to what fidler does. as i understand it creates a certificate for each website and install it and you don't have ant warning nassage from chrome when you uses fidler so it is possible.

Comment: That is interesting, I had not noticed that it works with Fiddler but fails with mitmproxy. This would mean the generated root CA certificate is different (I don't see any other possible difference, it may be one of the certificate extensions). I would recommend to you to create an issue in the [Mitmproxy project](https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues).